# Hibernate Transformers.aliasToBean vs AliasToBeanResultTransformer

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to know if anyone can explain to me what are difference in use of Transformers.aliasToBean() or class AliasToBeanResultTransformer? 
What are the advantages or disadvantage in the use of this two practise?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code of Transformers.aliasToBean() is:

```
public static ResultTransformer aliasToBean(Class target) {
    return new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(target);
}
```

So it just serves as a factory method for AliasToBeanResultTransformer. Using this factory method or calling the AliasToBeanResultTransformer directly is strictly equivalent.